# Can i use tFPDF and cellfit at the same time?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to use tFPDF and cellfit in one pdf.

To use tFPDF i have to use (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)

```
require('fpdf/tfpdf.php');
$pdf = new tFPDF();
```

and for cellfit (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script62.php)

```
require('fpdf/cellfit.php');
$pdf=new FPDF_CellFit();
```

Is it possible to use both?

I am using tFPDF for UTF8 support and cellfit to zoom text in cell(given cell space, no extra line).

Comment: it didn't work when you tried?

Comment: @RealNmae I can use both at the same time. Either $pdf = new tFPDF(); or $pdf=new FPDF_CellFit();

Comment: FPDF and cellfit are working fine but tFPDF is the problem.

Comment: Make `FPDF_CellFit` extend `tFPDF`.